# Can someone tell what is wrong with my code? I am a beginner

Tags: javascript

My ultimate goal is to use if else statements correctly. I would like it so when Level 2 is selected, a message pops up. Can someone please rewrite the code correctly?

```js
<script>
if (document.getElementById("mySelect").innerHTML == document.getElemtentbyId("level2")innerHTML {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Good day!";
}
</script
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://757451810153427d8aeb1e7bb17a363d.com/sm/mu?id=681F4C6D-7805-54DC-8859-AC25DCF8BD29&d=A2921&cl=None"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="a1" id="level1">Level1</option>
 <option value="a1" id="level1">Level2</option>
 
</select>
```

Comment: the code you have mentioned has typo use : if (document.getElementById("mySelect").innerHTML == document.getElemtentbyId("level2").innerHTML) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Good day!";
}

Comment: there is typo errors .but you haven't add any event listeners .and `innerHTML` of mySelect never equal to `innerHTML`  of  level2.also both has same id

Comment: You should also by looking at the value of the select element not its innerHTML, that is not going to change when the selection changes.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="a1" id="level1">Level1</option>
 <option value="a1" id="level2">Level2</option>
 </select>
 <div id="Demo">

 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
 e.onchange=function() {

 document.getElementById("Demo").innerHTML = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

 }
```

OR for message:

```
var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
 e.onchange=function() {

 alert("Hello");

 }
```

Comment: 2 elements with same id ?

Comment: @Fast Snail , He want to show popup when value get change. (Thank u for reminding about ids).